Beers not allowed in this enigmatic card puzzle
Beers are not allowed if you want win.


rot13(Gurer ner frireny pneqf ghearq hcfvqr qbja, ohg V qba'g xabj jung gb qb jvgu gurz lrg...)

@oAlt correct path

rot13(V frr svir hcfvqr qbja pneqf, 8p 7f 6u 5u naq 3p. Znccvat gurfr gb yrggref (fgnegvat ng 2p = N, 2q = O rgp.) guvf tvirf RBFKL (B FRKL?). Ubjrire V pna'g frr n ybtvpny nafjre urer, lrg.)

@sarsaparilla Rvtug bs urnegf vf nyfb vairegrq

Vg'f qrsvavgryl ABG fbzrguvat nobhg frk... Gur nafjre vf guerr yrggref ybat naq rnfvyl irevsvnoyr.
